# String slicing in python with curses

Tags: python, python-curses

## Note. This question relates to code originally submitted to codereview

See oringinal link at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101011/mengenlehreuhr-in-python

So I have written a clock. Not just any clock, the purpose of this clock is to crack [Kryptos section K4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptos).

Whilst the full source of the application is now [on GitHub](https://github.com/mproffitt/PyKryptos/blob/master/kryptos.py), the specific problem I am experiencing relates to the following method:

```
    def _update(self):
        self.window.erase()
        self.window.box()
        self.window.addstr(0, 1, str(self.index).zfill(2) + ' - ' + TimeDecipher.ciphertext[0:self.index])
        self.window.addstr(1, self.cipher_offset, TimeDecipher.ciphertext[0:self.index-1], self.color)
        self.window.addstr(
            1,
            (self.cipher_offset + self.index-1),
            TimeDecipher.ciphertext[self.index-1:self.index],
            self.highlight
        )
        self.window.addstr(1,
            (self.cipher_offset + self.index),
            TimeDecipher.ciphertext[self.index:],
            self.color
        )
        self.window.addstr(2, 1, ''.join(['-' for i in range(self.width - 2)]))
        for i, item in enumerate(self.lines):
            self.window.addstr((i + 3), 1, str(item))
        self.window.refresh()
```

The problem is described as follows.

When `self.index < len(self.time_decipher.ciphertext)` (97 characters), the highlighting works as anticipated.

```
OBKRUOX|O|GHULBSOLIFBBWFL...
```

However, when `self.index == ~96` I see this:

```
|AR|OBKRUOX...
```

Basically the last 2 characters are cut from the end of the printed string and dropped at the start.

Please can someone explain why this is happening and what I can do to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - There was an issue with counting.

The method which set `self.index` was being passed that information from another method meaning it was always 1 behind the value required for splicing and reset to 0 when it reached 97 (the length of the string).

Because the slicing works from 1 to return, when it reached 96, the index was actually -1 and 97 was 0.

Updated `Log::__add__` method to set index as:

```
    self.index = other.index if other.index > 0 else len(TimeDecipher.ciphertext) + other.index
```